# Fullcalendar SetDate on an event with AllDay doesn't work

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

The [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setDates) states that you can use the function like this:

```
event.setDates( start, end, [ options ] )
```

Where [ options ] accepts a plain object with a property of allDay of either true of false, however I can't seem to make this work, as I've tried multiple ways to do this. While events that have that property set by setDate() don't output any errors, they don't appear in the calendar as well.

What I have tried:

1. Storing an object in a variable and using that variable:

```js
year = calendar.getDate().getFullYear();
var all_day_object = {
    allDay: true,
};
calendar.getEventById('new_year').setDates(`${year}-01-01`, `${year}-01-01`, all_day_object);
```

2. Setting it as true and hoping for the best:

```js
year = calendar.getDate().getFullYear();
calendar.getEventById('new_year').setDates(`${year}-01-01`, `${year}-01-01`, true);
```

3. Creating an object with brackets in the same line:

```js
year = calendar.getDate().getFullYear();
calendar.getEventById('new_year').setDates(`${year}-01-01`, `${year}-01-01`, {allDay: true});
```

While I can achieve the same effect with this code:

```js
year = calendar.getDate().getFullYear();
calendar.getEventById('new_year').setDates(`${year}-01-01`, `${year}-01-01`);
calendar.getEventById('new_year').setAllDay(true);
```

I want to do in a one line to simplify my code.

Comment: The bug seems specifically when setting allDay: true. If you set allDay: false using that option, it works fine. Also, you've tagged v4, which is unlikely to see any fixes now, but the bug seems to still exist in the new v5 - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWKbZYx . I'd suggest reporting a bug: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs